# Select previous sibling of input by backspace in javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I have an input field with the name box. I can move forward after input by

```
box.addEventListener('input', function () {
  if(!isNaN(parseInt(box.value))){
    box.value = "";
  }else if(box != null){
    box.nextSibling.focus();
  }
});
```

And it's working alright. I wish to move to the previous sibling of the input by backspace, and I am doing it by the previous sibling and kind of the same logic

```
box.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if(e.key == 'Backspace' && box != null){ 
    box.previousSibling.focus();
  }
})
```

But doing this only works for the first backspace properly, for the rest of the inputs I need to backspace twice. I tried with the `keydown` event too and even that wasn't perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that (in the browsers you and I are using) `input` events are processed before `keyup` events, so you press backspace on a non-empty box and a character is deleted, so `input` is processed then the next sibling is selected, then the `keyup` is processed and you move to the previous sibling, which looks like going nowhere.

You can fix this by storing the box where the value changed, then if that reference is not `null` on backspace `keyup` you can move to the previous sibling of the box where the `keyup` event fired, otherwise move to the previous sibling of the box where the input event fired.

```js
const boxes = document.getElementById('boxes');
let inputInput = null;
for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
  const box = document.createElement('input');
  box.type="text"
  box.addEventListener('input', function (e) 
  {
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(box.value)))
    {
      box.value = "";
    }
    else if(box != null)
    {
      inputInput = box;
      box.nextSibling.focus();
      
    }
  });
  box.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) 
  {
    if(e.key == 'Backspace' && box != null)
    {
      if(inputInput == null)
      {
        box.previousSibling.focus();
      }
      else
      {
        inputInput.previousSibling.focus();
        inputInput = null;
      }
    }
  });
  boxes.appendChild(box);
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
</div>
```

The problem with this solution is that event precedence is not part of the specification, so this is not necessarily cross browser compatible, i.e. in some browsers `keyup` might happen before `input`.